# Where exactly does the 30% commission on appstore sales go?

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, google-play

Google Play and Apple's AppStore both take a 30% cut from paid app sales. ["distribution partner and operating fees"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=112622&topic=15867&ctx=topic) is where Google Play's 30% apparently goes. I'm wondering exactly who these middlemen are?

For Apple, I'm assuming it's Apple who receives the cut directly. I have heard some people say that these so-called partners are the telco carriers but this doesn't make sense for the large number of devices that aren't necessarily a phone or tied to any carrier company, for example somebody who just does all their shopping over WiFi with no carrier contract.

No doubt the case is different from country to country but if anybody could shed some light on who these people are I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

This is only speculation, as nobody really knows. I assume money for the most part goes to Apple/Google, that's would explain why Apple's Appstore has been extremely profitable to them. Although they might have to pay some distribution partners... Operating fees is paying for servers, and anything else they want to do. Basically money banked for companies.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the mobile operator, the handset manufacturer, any payment processor Google uses in the country, as well as the foreign exchange fees (if applicable). But, really this isn't appropriate for stack overflow.